# Code Error in Excel 2003

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2003

I have a code that runs absolutely fine with excel 2007 but its not running with excel 2003. It gives "complie error" and this line turns red.

```
 Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:= _
```

Your suggestions would help a lot. Thanks. Please let me know if you need any information from my side.

Here is my full code:

```
'-------------------------------------
' Create Final Report
'-------------------------------------
Sub FinalReport()
Dim thisWb As Workbook
Set thisWb = ActiveWorkbook
Dim btn, rght As Long
Dim NewWbk As String

NewWbk = "Final_Report"

' Add a new workbook
    Application.Workbooks.Add
    Range("A1").Select
' Rename the workbook
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=thisWb.Path & Application.PathSeparator & "Final_Report" & ".xls"

    Windows("Tool_01082013.xls").Activate
    Sheets("Reports").Activate

' select the sheet and range to be copied
Range("B2:AO34").Select

' Copy the selected range...
    Selection.Copy
    Workbooks("Final_Report.xls").Sheets("Sheet1").Activate

' and Paste it into the new workbook
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:= _
        False, Transpose:=False

Windows("Tool_01082013.xls").Activate
    Sheets("Reports_Month").Activate

' select the sheet and range to be copied
Range("A1:DR34").Select

' Copy the selected range...
    Selection.Copy
    Workbooks("Final_Report.xls").Sheets("Sheet2").Activate

' and Paste it into the new workbook
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:= _
        False, Transpose:=False
Workbooks("Final_Report.xls").Save
Workbooks("Final_Report.xls").Close
Windows("Tool_01082013.xls").Activate
    With Sheets("Reports")
        .Activate
        .Range("A5").Select  '-- move focus to the first item
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Try replacing xlValues with xlPasteValues and xlNone with xlPasteSpecialOperationNone

Comment: Right, I got the versions mixed up; thought you were having trouble in 2007. I'm testing in 2007; can't test in 2003. Sorry :/

Comment: Abusing "selection. " is evil. Aside from that I'd try removing all arguments to the PasteSpecial call except from xlValues. Also, what's the error ? I left my crystal ball at work ;)

Comment: @AlexandreP.Levasseur It just says compile syntax error. And the line that I have mentioned in my quesiton turns red.

Comment: @AlexandreP.Levasseur good point, the copy and paste code can be entirely replaced by using things like `Workbooks("Final_Report.xls").Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:AN33").Value = Workbooks("Tool_01082013.xls").Sheets("Reports").Range("B2:AO34").Value`

Comment: @mkingston `xlPasteValues` (-4163) and `xlPasteSpecialOperationNone` (-4142) are indeed correct for Excel 2003 - see the "xlPasteType" and "XlPastespecialOperation" enumerations [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa221100%28v=office.11%29.aspx) but `xlValues` (-4163, defined via "xlFindLookIn") and `xlNone` (-4142, defined via "Excel.Constants") exist with the correct values in other enumerations

Comment: @barrowc yeah I tested for that but thought that maybe it was actually checking the enum type, realising the symbol didn't belong to that specific enum type and throwing an error. It was a shot in the dark, really.

Comment: @mkingston How can I paste special (values) using the code lines that you have mentioned? I might not be understanding it right?

Comment: Okay, I am not an VBA expert. Can you please tell me what you all are are discussing that might point to what I should change in my code?

Comment: Added an answer with code. Let me know how it goes.

Comment: Sorry, made a small edit in the code after copying it from the editor. Turns out it introduced an error. Assuming makes an ass of me... It's fixed now :).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this out:

```
'-------------------------------------
' Create Final Report
'-------------------------------------
Sub FinalReport()

    Dim thisWb As Workbook, _
        finalReport as Workbook, _
        toolWB as Workbook
    Set thisWb = ActiveWorkbook
    Dim copyrange As Range

    ' Add a new workbook
    set finalReport = Application.Workbooks.Add
    ' Rename the workbook
    finalReport.SaveAs Filename:=thisWb.Path & Application.PathSeparator & "Final_Report.xls"

    set toolWB = Workbooks("Tool_01082013.xls")
    Set copyrange = toolWB.Sheets("Reports").Range("B2:AO34")
    finalReport.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Resize(copyrange.Rows.Count, copyrange.Columns.Count).Value = copyrange.Value
    Set copyrange = toolWB.Sheets("Reports_Month").Range("A1:DR34")
    finalReport.Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A1").Resize(copyrange.Rows.Count, copyrange.Columns.Count).Value = copyrange.Value

    finalReport.Save
    finalReport.Close
    Application.Goto toolWB.Sheets("Reports").Range("A5")

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank yuo so much guys! What ultimately worked is when I replacedxlValues with xlPasteValues and xlNone with xlPasteSpecialOperationNone. Thanks Again